# Add prefix to all strings with specific pattern in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I have a pattern of strings that I want to add prefix to it. What is the best way to achieve this?

I am able to find using regex but I am not sure how can I replace with prefix and maintaining the original strings that fits the pattern.

Example:

Find all strings with regex: `<!--.*-->`

Replace with:`<!-- Date -->`+[Original string]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add examples of the strings you are working with, and the prefix you want to add. As it stands, this question is unclear.

Comment: @MattDMo: I am trying to make it general case. Editting it to make it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **Replace** feature with the "Regular Expression" option enabled.

- You can use the default shortcut for the replace feature of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> on Windows/Linux or <kbd>option</kbd> +<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> on Mac.
- You can use the default shortcut for the regex option of 
  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> Windows/Linux or <kbd>option</kbd> +<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>)
- type your regular expression into the *Find What* box
- type the string you want to use as a prefix in the *Replace With* box. Make sure to use grouping (parentheses around the string) so you can reference it in the replace.

**Example:**

Say you are looking for any string that has "bar" in it and want to prefix it with "foo":

- *Find What* box: `(bar)`
- *Replace With* box: `foo$1`

As you can see, we referenced the grouping expression (the regex inside the parentheses) with the `$1` symbol.

Hit *replace* to do it one by one, or *replace all* to do all of them in the file.

Edit to tailor response to more specific information given:

**Before Replace All:** 
[image: Before Replace All]

**After Replace All:**
[image: After Replace All]

Just realized you may have meant this:

**Before Replace All 2:** 
[image: Before Replace All 2]
**After Replace All 2:**
[image: After Replace All 2]

Answer (score 0):

In order for `\1` to work, you need to have a capturing group. In **Find What**, put in

```
(<!--.*-->)
```

(the parentheses create the first capture group). Then, in **Replace With**, put in

```
<!-- Date --> \1
```